# How generate static library (.a) from shared for dynamic linking

Tags: shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a shared library **librun.so** without source code, but have an SDK to work with it.

How generate static library (**librun.a**) with only export functions from **librun.so** for dynamic linking my library **libapp.so** with **librun.so**?

On windows it's done like this, but on Linux how?

> 1. dumpbin /exports run.dll
> 2. Make run.def with export functions
> 3. lib /def:run.def /out:run.lib /machine:x86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux you normally don't need explicit static library and just link against shared library directly:

```
$ gcc ... -o libapp.so -Lpath/to/librun.so -lrun
```

If you really need an static library, you can generate it via [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so):

```
# Generate wrappers
$ implib-gen.py librun.so
Generating librun.so.tramp.S...
Generating librun.so.init.c...
# Create static library
$ gcc -c -fPIC librun.so.tramp.S librun.so.init.c
$ ar rcs librun.a librun.so.*.o
```

Note that resulting static library `librun.a` will be a *wrapper* which internally loads original `librun.so` and forwards calls to it (this is same as Windows).